# In vim, how do I substitute a regex pattern with whitespace?

Tags: vim

In my specific case I have

```
(function(){
```

and I want to replace that with

```
<whitespace char>xxx<whitespace char>
```

so it would go from

```
$('#myId').click(function(){do_something()})
```

to

```
$('#myId').click xxx do_something()})
```

I've tried

```
:s%/(function(){/ xxx /g
```

but it throws an error
throws an error 'E486:  Pattern not found' even though I can find just /(function(){/.  Nor does trying to add a \s to the replacement text work.

(sorry about the weird formatting of this question.  doesn't really flow well)

Comment: Do you need the `%` and do you need the `g` flag? `%` operates on all lines, `g` on all occurrences.

Comment: I tried it on `vim 7.2.18` and it did **NOT** like s%. This isn't so much a question about how to use vim, but rather to point out a simple (but understandable) mistake the OP made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

transposed the s and %

```
:s%/(function(){/ xxx /g
```

should become

```
:%s/(function(){/ xxx /g
```

I tried it and it works for me.

the former returns 
E486: Pattern not found: /(function(){/ xxx /g

Answer (score 3):

Your only problem is that it should be `:%s` not `:s%`.

`:%` specifies the whole file as the range for the following Ex command.

`:s%` means use '%' as the regex separator character (instead of /).  So in your query, you aren't finding "/(function" in the current line.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape some characters

```
:s%/\(function\(\)\{/ xxx /g
```

Comment: my thought at first too, but its much simpler. the s and % have been transposed

Comment: So you have to escape some character if it *is* special?